# NSTextField is not working over Full Screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

`NSTextfield` is not working when I make a full screen app.
I have also made first responder of textfield. How can I make it enable and working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full Screen window won't get any keyboard events the way it is, due to the fact that it was created with with the `NSBorderlessWindowMask` style mask. Apparently windows of this type can't become "key windows". However, you can fix this problem by subclassing `NSWindow` and overriding the `canBecomeKeyWindow` method.

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @Deepika How exactly do you subclass the NSWindow and override the canBecomeKeyWindow method?